# Is donating money to charities / non-profits with a credit card considered a cash advance transaction?

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, cash-advance

I'm UK based. I know that credit cards charge extra cash transaction fees for not only getting cash from the ATM but also for things which are not *quite* cash like crypto, gift cards or gambling. Is donating money to a charity also considered a cash advance purchase?

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, they are a cash advance.

I used to make donations using my credit card, and that was never an issue. Recently, however, when I was about to make one, for some unknown reason I decided to check my bank's credit card policies again. It was fortunate that I did so, because now they consider all donations to be a cash advance.

*Any donation from a credit card will be treated as a cash advance.*
https://tinyurl.com/5enyp47c

I looked at other banks and as far as I am aware, this is the case for all standard credit cards in Australia.

Comment: I donate to a US charity every month using a CC, and it’s always registered as a purchase.  Obviously Australia’s banks and banking regulations are abominable and greedy.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not.  It is processed like a purchase at a store.

Comment: I do actually agree with this (from personal experience), however as an answer it really needs some kind of citation or additional reference.

Comment: @Vicky it's *unwise* to take a screenshot of your checking account web page in order to prove that the charity charges it like a purchase.

Comment: @RonJohn agreed, which is why I didn't say "Please take a screenshot of your checking account web page to support this claim". A good citation would be a link to Ts and Cs of a credit card provider that specifically references charity donations, or similar.

Comment: @Vicky who memorizes their CC providers' Ts and Cs?

Comment: @Vicky, I think personal experience is sufficient here.  Any support would be excessively tedious to find.

Comment: @RonJohn I cannot read about "memorizing the Ts and Cs", they (usually) are easy to be looked in and searched.

Comment: There is a rather old (2012) but good page at https://www.moneysupermarket.com/press-releases/when-is-your-credit-card-not-a-credit-card/ which surveys the "Definition of Cash Transaction" across 10 different credit cards.  They're all basically the same: it applies to obtaining money or money-like things (although gift cards aren't mentioned), or gambling-related transactions.  I certainly don't see charity donations mentioned as included by any though.

Comment: My experience is also that they don't, but may not be so cut & dry — these are obviously not definitive, but here's a [thread from 2007, claiming they were charged interest on a charity donation with NatWest](https://www.accountantforums.com/threads/natwest-mastercard-interest-charged-on-charity-donations.135154/) and [one from 2018 about a Tesco Credit Card](https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/discussion/5864222/warning-tesco-cc-now-charge-you-fee-if-you-give-to-charity). Maybe it's down to individual companies?